# Preventing component creation - Delphi

Tags: delphi, components

I am creating an application which makes use of several TTabsheets (from the TPageControl component).  Is it possible to prevent a component (in this case a tab) from being created during the program startup?  I want to manually create the tabs at a later stage.

This is not a dynamic component.  It was created in the Delphi 2010 IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you create them at design time in the first place ?

Comment: just remove those sheets in the IDE

Comment: It helps to simplify the design process as I am still quite a beginner at programming.

Comment: I can't remove the tabs as they are a vital to the functionality of the program

Comment: If they're such a vital part of the functionality, why do you want to prevent them from being created? You can't have it both ways - you either create them at design-time in the IDE (in which case they're automatically created when the form is created at runtime) or you create them at run-time in your code.

Comment: @Ken or you create them at design time in a frame and create that frame dynamically

Comment: @David: Sure. Or you put them on a form  that is not auto-created at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include components in the designer, then they will be created when the form is created. Nothing you can do to stop that.

The logical conclusion is that you need to create the components at run time. One obvious way to make that easier is to put the components on a frame and create that at run time. That will allow you to group related components and do the visual design and property specification at design time, but then postpone creation until you know you need them.

Comment: Thank you very much David!  I shall give the frame a try.

Comment: Frankly that's a better approach than the answer you accepted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188910/how-to-dynamically-create-customized-tabsheet-runtime

Comment: I see what you are saying.  The problem I had was the extensive amount of code that has to be written to create a component when the whole component/layout is already designed.  I only have a couple of weeks to finish this school project.